# Preview column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

When I am working with Rstudio I often cannot remember the name of a column so i will type `data_frame$` and then a few letters that I think are in the column name and various potential column names containing that string will pop up, and i will select the correct one. Is there anyway of getting this same functionality in vscode when working with pandas? Currently I have to look at `subject_csv.columns.values` and find the name of the colum im interested in which is a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
dataframe.info()
dataframe.head() - will show 5 first rows  with columns names by default
dataframe.describe() - detailes info on DF
```

Comment: Sorry I may not have been clear-  Im looking for a way to quickly browse through column names while typing. These suggestions work worse than dataframe.columns.values